# Are there any JSON serializers for C# .Net 4.0+ that serialize JSON to Dictionary<string,dynamic> and dynamic[]

Tags: c#, .net, json, c#-4.0, dynamic

I know you can serialize JSON to Dictionary and object[], but the problem is that it requires you to constantly cast things all over the place:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

var json = new JavaScriptSerializer { }.DeserializeObject(@"{array:['item1','item2']}") as Dictionary<string, object>;
var strings = new List<string> { };
if (json != null)
{
    var array = json["array"] as object[];
    if (array != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in array.Select(i=>i as string))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
            {
                strings.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
return strings.ToArray();
```

I would much rather do something more like:

```
try
{
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer { }.DeserializeDynamic(@"{array:['item1','item2']}") as Dictionary<string, dynamic>;
    var strings = new List<string>{};
    foreach (var item in json["array"])
        strings.Add(item as string);
    return strings.ToArray();
}
catch { return null; }
```

I have run into problems with object[] and number types, I'm never sure if it's going to be an int, a float, a decimal, or a double etc. I can't sanitize my json data so it reliably is only a double...

Are there any JSON Serializers for .Net 4.0 that output Dictionary and dynamic[]? That just seams like a more natural choice for working with json then Dictionary and object[]...

Answer (score 1):

[JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) should handle your needs (with the [Json.NET Dynamic Extensions](http://weblogs.asp.net/britchie/archive/2010/08/05/json-net-dynamic-extensions.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary<string, object>` and `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` are the same types as far runtime is concerned.

For example this works:

```
var dynDic =new Dictionary<string,object>{ {"test", 1}}
                    as Dictionary<string,dynamic>;
int value = dynDic["test"];
```

So if your first works:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer { }
         .DeserializeObject(@"{array:['item1','item2']}") 
         as Dictionary<string, object>;
```

then so should:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer { }
         .DeserializeDynamic(@"{array:['item1','item2']}")
         as Dictionary<string, dynamic>;
```

But then :

```
foreach (var item in json["array"])
    strings.Add(item as string);
```

doesn't use dynamic invocation so it compiles that same whether the item `var` was `object` or `dynamic` so if you are having problems my guess is it's in the use of `dynamic`.

Same rule applies to `object[]` and `dynamic[]`, they are the same type, you can freely cast between them, when you cast you are just telling the compiler how to use the `object`s from that array.

```
dynamic[] dynArr = new object[]{1};
```

So the answer is that anything that will deserialize to `Dictionary<string,object>` or `object[]` can be used as `Dictionary<string,dynamic>` or `dynamic[]`